# How do I convert a number to a weekday character in R?

Tags: r

I'm currently working on a project in which I have a column called 'weekday'. This column contains day numbers 0:6. I'm new to R and want to create a new column that has weekday abbreviations for each number e.g. "0 = Sun, 1 = Mon", etc. Below is an image of my dataframe I am working with. Any help and tips would be much apppreciated.

[Image of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSQea.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can add your zero based weekday index to `2017-01-01`, which was a Sunday.

```sql
x <- c(0:6)
days_abbrev <- substr(weekdays(as.Date("2017-01-01") + x), 1, 3)
days_abbrev

[1] "Sun" "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" "Fri" "Sat"
```

Or using the excellent suggestion by @DarrenTsai we can pass `TRUE` as the second parameter to `weekdays()` to use abbreviations:

```r
weekdays(as.Date("2017-01-01") + x, TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly from the date column using `%a` format...

```
format(as.Date("2017-01-05"), "%a")
[1] "Thu"
```

Comment: The OP is wanting to convert an integer ordinal number 0, 1, 2 into Sun, Mon, Tue, rather than converting a date directly.